# Passing 'this' to another object constructor during contruction in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, class, this

Ok so here's my code;

```
function stdTile(gameObjectargs)
{   
    gameObjectargs.parent=this;
    this.gameObject=new gameObject(gameObjectargs);
}
```

Basically all I wanna do is pass 'This' to gameObject, so I can refer back to the stdTile  when I use `new stdTile({});`
but for some reason every time I call it its sets `gameObject.parent` to `window` any help?

::EDIT::

I dont understand why my code didnt appear but I made a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Wjmta/

Comment: your question is unclear, please include a fiddle.

Comment: im not sure what you trying to do, but 1 `this` is a keyword 2 functions cannot create variable's to be used outside of them, i cantt see your code and dont understand your question, but this may help.

Comment: Could you explain the way you're trying to access the `parent` property after instanciation? A code sample would be useful.

Comment: just typing my new stdTile object into the console then navigating into the gameObject property, and then to the parent property which is equal to window

Comment: The only way I can reproduce that behavior is omitting the `new` keyword when attempting to create the stdTile instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work as expected; here's an example:

```
function gameObject(args)
{
    this.parent = args.parent;
    this.args = args;
}

function stdTile(gameObjectargs)
{   
    gameObjectargs.parent=this;
    this.gameObject=new gameObject(gameObjectargs);
}

var tile = new stdTile({});
console.log(tile.gameObject.parent === tile); // true
```

Comment: I got the same result without changing anything in the original code. I guess the `new` keyword is missing somewhere... Furthermore, why this `variable` property (`obj.parent.variable`)?

Comment: Oh wow, turns out everything was fine except in function gameObject I had this.parent=parent instead of this.parent=args.parent I had no idea parent returned the window object, or is it a keyword? anyways thanks for your help everyone!:)

Comment: `obj.parent.variable` was just an easy way of shortening down my long code Its actually a collision detection system for a game I'm working on, the gameObjects are sorted through to find which ones collide with certain areas then they're stored in an array and there needs to be a way to tell which object they belong to:)